# Bulk import hundreds of documents into new document library and retain all links

Tags: import, bulk, embedded

Is there a way to bulk load hundreds of MS Word documents and retain all hyperlinks within each document?

Comment: You are asking how to ensure that the links still works, right?

Answer (score 0):

- For On-premise:

> You can go into Explorer View, and Copy/paste multiple items from
>   wherever using normal Windows methods(right click, Edit/Copy, etc.) 
>   The copy/paste only works in Explorer View, not the All Documents
>   view.

- For Office 365 as well as On-premise:

> You can "Sync" the library to your system via One Drive and copy/paste the documents in similar way as that for On-premise.

Comment: For on prem, while Explorer View works, it can time out if there are a lot of documents or large ones... I have found using Beyond Compare to be a much better option.

Comment: @ChrisFells You can either increase the limit on the client system by following this [link](http://kx.cloudingenium.com/microsoft/servers/sharepoint/sharepoint-error-0x800700df-file-size-exceeds-limit-allowed-saved/) OR use One Drive to copy/paste.